# MODULE NOT FOUND: date-fns/is_after

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

My package.json conatins "date-fns": "^2.0.0-beta.4".

i downloaded a React JS theme its was working fine but now suddenly it is throwing an error saying module not found.

`import isAfter from 'date-fns/is_after';`

It says module not found.

Comment: This kind of import has been removed from the v2 release: https://gist.github.com/kossnocorp/a307a464760b405bb78ef5020a4ab136

Comment: i solved the error i have posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

The code was written in TypeScript as import isAfter from 'date-fns/is_after';

The issue got resolved by changing it to import { isAfter } from 'date-fns';